# Does .val() support returning as integer or float?

Tags: jquery

I just wrote a piece of code where I do a basic comparison:

HTML is:

```
<input id="someInputField" />
```

Javascript is:

```
var someVariableThatIsANumber = 1123.23
if (someVariableThatIsANumber > $("someInputField").val()) { 
   // do something
}
```

The code works, in the sense that it returns TRUE if the value of someInputField is a number bigger than 1123.23, and returns false if it's less than 1123.23. My question is: why?

I ask, because [val() should return a string](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and not be able to compare it. Why does it and work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a String which is implicitly converted into proper numeric value by JavaScript engine.

Generally JavaScript uses implicit convertion to fit of different classes.

The same is with the opposite case when you do `"something" + 1`. Then `1` is converted into a String.

Answer (score 0):

It works because when you compare a string with a number, the string is first converted to a number too for that conversion.

From [the MDN on comparisons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirect=no) :

> When comparing a number and a string, the string is converted to a
>   number value. JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric
>   literal to a Number type value

Be careful not to compare a string to another string as `"33"<"9"` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

=== comparing without convert types

== comparing with convert types